# How can I link an SMTP server to a Docker container under Plesk Onyx?

Tags: docker, plesk

I'm running a Docker container on a Plesk Onyx managed server using the Docker extension. Everything is fine except email. How do I go about either linking my smtp server to the container or modifying the Docker files to setup an external smtp server? Everything I'm finding out there doesn't seem to match up with the Plesk version of Docker.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? If so, care to share :) ?

Comment: No I did not. Wasn't a different way but still wish I could use docker